# ACL can method in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, acl

I did a simple ACL system on my application with the following tables:

employees->roles->roles_permissions<-permissions

I also have the models for employees, roles and permissions tables.

And now I want to implement a 'can' method where I give a permission slug and it returns true or false.

So far I tried (unsuccessfully) the following approach (which I used with no problems on my 'is' method):

```
public function can($slug)
{
    return $this->role->permissions->slug == $slug;
}
```

How can I make my 'can' method to work as I expect?

Answer (score 0):

What have I done since I asked:

```
    public function can($slug)
    {
        return $this->role->permissions->where('slug', $slug)->first()->slug == $slug;
    }
```

Don't know if it's the best approach, but it's working.

Comment: You could just look for the permission:
return $this->role->permissions->where('slug', $slug)->count() > 0;